# Wordpress 4.7.6 vulnerabilities?

Tags: vulnerability, wordpress

I have a wordpress 4.7.6 without plugins, however, I've noticed this: https://cxsecurity.com/cveshow/CVE-2017-14723 And the other vulnerabilities that are <4.8.2.

My question is, I have tried to search how to exploit it in my wordpress, but I do not find how. I appreciate your help and well, I am assuming that if it is <4.8.2, it is vulnerable, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.7.6) you will see that WordPress versions `4.8.1` and **earlier** are affected by nine security issues:

> 1. $wpdb->prepare() can create unexpected and unsafe queries leading to potential SQL injection (SQLi). WordPress core is not directly
>      vulnerable to this issue, but we’ve added hardening to prevent plugins
>      and themes from accidentally causing a vulnerability. Reported by
>      Slavco.
> 2. A cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability was discovered in the oEmbed discovery. Reported by xknown of the WordPress Security
>      Team.
> 3. A cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability was discovered in the visual editor. Reported by Rodolfo Assis (@brutelogic) of Sucuri
>      Security.
> 4. A path traversal vulnerability was discovered in the file unzipping code. Reported by Alex Chapman (noxrnet).
> 5. A cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability was discovered in the plugin editor. Reported by 陈瑞琦 (Chen Ruiqi).
> 6. An open redirect was discovered on the user and term edit screens. Reported by Yasin Soliman (ysx).
> 7. A path traversal vulnerability was discovered in the customizer. Reported by Weston Ruter of the WordPress Security Team.
> 8. A cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability was discovered in template names. Reported by Luka (sikic).
> 9. A cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability was discovered in the link modal. Reported by Anas Roubi (qasuar).

So yes, you should updated your Wordpress to the latest one.

Comment: Exactly, I have reviewed that, but I would like to exploit them, say, know how the xss is done in my reflected wordpress 4.7.6 and I have searched all the information for it and do not give PoC how to do it ... @Mirsad

Comment: Or for example, in which attack vector is that SQL injection

Comment: How can I be sure that you will not use that against someone else?

Comment: I have my wordpress in my localhost, I just want to learn. If I really wanted to use that against someone, I would not be around ...

Comment: If you realy want to learn, than learn to understand how vulnerable code works from coding perspective - if you come here and ask: "can you find me an exploit for this or that..." - how is that learning?

Comment: I do not want a Mirsad exploit, I just want to know the attack vector for example XSS or SQL injection. I would really know how it works and besides, I would go to the code fragment to know why that happened

Answer (score 0):

Because CVE-2017-14723 affects the framework, it enables the possibility for a SQLi attack in themes and plug-ins. There is not a direct PoC, as it would depend on the implementation.

A little more digging, and I found this: https://vuldb.com/?id.107044

> There are known technical details, but no exploit is available.